# First contact with C++ - Graphics Library

Tags: c++, c++20

I am trying to learn C++ by writing a basic graphics library; undergrad-toy-project level.

I am trying to write modern C++ (C++ 20 standard), but avoiding features that are not well supported by my IDE (VS Code), such as modules. As I come from a C, Python, and C# background there may be some code smells / biases.

Can you guys please provide me some feedback? The code is not complete by any means, but I would like to know if I am on the right path before continuing.

Thanks in advance.

Obs, requires libX11-dev and linux (?).

edit: I just copied the debug compiler flags from some random post on the internet.
edit 2: forgot to add main.cpp

**src/universes.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>

namespace cg {

class Point2D {
private:
    float _x;
    float _y;
    float _h;

public:
    Point2D(float x, float y, float h)
        : _x(x), _y(y), _h(h) {
        assert(std::isfinite(x));
        assert(std::isfinite(y));
        assert(std::isfinite(h));
        assert(h != 0);
    }

    Point2D(float x, float y) : Point2D(x, y, 1) {}

    auto x() const { return this->_x; }
    auto y() const { return this->_y; }
    auto h() const { return this->_h; }
};

class NormalizedPoint2D {
private:
    float _x;
    float _y;

public:
    NormalizedPoint2D(float x, float y)
        : _x(x), _y(y) {
        assert(0 <= x && x <= 1);
        assert(0 <= y && y <= 1);
    }

    auto x() const { return this->_x; }
    auto y() const { return this->_y; }
};

class Window {
private:
    float _min_x;
    float _min_y;
    float _max_x;
    float _max_y;

public:
    Window(float min_x, float min_y, float max_x, float max_y);

    auto min_x() const { return this->_min_x; }
    auto min_y() const { return this->_min_y; }
    auto max_x() const { return this->_max_x; }
    auto max_y() const { return this->_max_y; }

    auto contains(Point2D pt) const {
        return this->_min_x <= pt.x() && pt.x() <= this->_max_x && this->_min_y <= pt.y() && pt.y() <= this->_max_y;
    }
};

Window::Window(float min_x, float min_y, float max_x, float max_y)
    : _min_x(min_x),
      _min_y(min_y),
      _max_x(max_x),
      _max_y(max_y) {
    assert(std::isfinite(min_x));
    assert(std::isfinite(min_y));
    assert(std::isfinite(max_x));
    assert(std::isfinite(max_y));

    assert(min_x < max_x);
    assert(min_y < max_y);
}

// Naive normalization function, only handles points contained in the window
NormalizedPoint2D normalize(const Point2D pt, const Window &win) {
    assert(win.contains(pt));

    const auto x_without_h = pt.x() / pt.h();
    const auto y_without_h = pt.y() / pt.h();

    const auto delta_x = win.max_x() - win.min_x();
    const auto delta_y = win.max_y() - win.min_y();

    const auto final_x = (x_without_h - win.min_x()) / delta_x;
    const auto final_y = (y_without_h - win.min_y()) / delta_y;

    return NormalizedPoint2D(final_x, final_y);
}

} // namespace cg
```

**src/colors.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <bit>
#include <cassert>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <vector>

namespace cg {

const float MIN_COLOR_INTENSITY = 0.0;
const float MAX_COLOR_INTENSITY = 1.0;
const std::uint8_t MIN_CHANNEL_VALUE = 0;
const std::uint8_t MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE = 255;

// Used to index colors in a Palette
using ColorId = std::int32_t;

// In-memory representation of a color (ARGB)
using DeviceColor = std::uint32_t;

class Color {
private:
    float _r;
    float _g;
    float _b;

public:
    Color(float r, float g, float b) {
        assert(0 <= r && r <= 1);
        assert(0 <= g && g <= 1);
        assert(0 <= b && b <= 1);

        this->_r = r;
        this->_g = g;
        this->_b = b;
    }

    auto red() const { return this->_r; }
    auto green() const { return this->_r; }
    auto blue() const { return this->_r; }

    std::uint32_t to_uint32() const {
        static_assert(std::endian::native == std::endian::little);

        auto value = static_cast<std::uint32_t>(MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE) << 24;
        value |= (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE * this->_r) << 16);
        value |= (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE * this->_g) << 8);
        value |= static_cast<std::uint32_t>(MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE * this->_b);
        return value;
    }

    auto to_device_color() const {
        return this->to_uint32();
    }
};

using Palette = std::vector<Color>;

} // namespace cg
```

and the real meat, **src/devices.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

#include "colors.h"
#include "universes.h"

namespace cg {

class DevicePoint {
private:
    std::size_t _x;
    std::size_t _y;

public:
    DevicePoint(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) : _x(x), _y(y) {}

    auto x() const { return this->_x; }
    auto y() const { return this->_y; }
};

class Device {
private:
    std::size_t _num_columns;
    std::size_t _num_rows;
    std::unique_ptr<ColorId[]> _buffer;

    auto _get_offset(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const { return (this->_num_columns * y) + x; }
    auto _num_pixels() const { return this->_num_columns * this->_num_rows; }

    void _validate_palette(const Palette &palette) const;
    auto _to_x11buffer(const Palette &palette) const;

public:
    Device(std::size_t num_columns, std::size_t num_rows);

    auto num_columns() const { return this->_num_columns; }
    auto num_rows() const { return this->_num_rows; }
    auto contains(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const { return x < this->_num_columns && y < this->_num_rows; }
    auto get(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const;
    void set(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, ColorId color_id);
    void show(const Palette &palette) const;
};

class ViewPort {
private:
    std::size_t _x;
    std::size_t _y;
    std::size_t _num_columns;
    std::size_t _num_rows;
    std::shared_ptr<Device> _device;

    void draw_vertical_line(std::size_t x, std::size_t y0, std::size_t y1, ColorId color_id);

public:
    ViewPort(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t num_columns, std::size_t num_rows, const std::shared_ptr<Device> device);

    auto x() const { return this->_x; }
    auto y() const { return this->_y; }

    auto num_columns() const { return this->_num_columns; }
    auto num_rows() const { return this->_num_rows; }

    auto contains(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const;
    auto get(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const;
    void set(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, ColorId color_id);
    void draw_line(std::size_t x0, std::size_t y0, std::size_t x1, std::size_t y1, ColorId color_id);
};

Device::Device(std::size_t num_columns, std::size_t num_rows)
    : _num_columns(num_columns), _num_rows(num_rows) {
    assert(num_columns >= 1);
    assert(num_rows >= 1);

    this->_buffer = std::make_unique<ColorId[]>(num_columns * num_rows);
}

void Device::_validate_palette(const Palette &palette) const {
    assert(palette.size() > 0);

    const auto buffer_size = this->_num_pixels();
    const auto palette_size = palette.size();

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < buffer_size; i++) {
        const auto color_id = this->_buffer[i];
        assert(color_id >= 0);

        const auto color_id_cast = static_cast<std::size_t>(color_id);
        assert(color_id_cast < palette_size);
    };
}

auto Device::_to_x11buffer(const Palette &palette) const {
    const auto memory = malloc(this->_num_pixels() * sizeof(DeviceColor));
    const auto x_buffer = static_cast<DeviceColor *>(memory);

    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < this->_num_rows; y++) {
        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < this->_num_columns; x++) {
            const auto this_buffer_offset = this->_get_offset(x, y);

            const auto color_id = static_cast<std::size_t>(this->_buffer[this_buffer_offset]);
            const auto color = palette[color_id];
            const auto device_color = color.to_device_color();

            const auto x_buffer_offset = ((this->_num_rows - y - 1) * this->_num_columns) + x;

            x_buffer[x_buffer_offset] = device_color;
        }
    }

    return static_cast<void *>(x_buffer);
}

auto Device::get(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const {
    assert(this->contains(x, y));

    auto offset = this->_get_offset(x, y);
    return this->_buffer[offset];
}

void Device::set(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, ColorId color_id) {
    assert(this->contains(x, y));

    auto offset = this->_get_offset(x, y);
    this->_buffer[offset] = color_id;
}

void Device::show(const Palette &palette) const {
    this->_validate_palette(palette);

    auto *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    assert(display != NULL);

    auto window = ::XCreateSimpleWindow(
        display,
        DefaultRootWindow(display),
        0,                  /* window x */
        0,                  /* window y*/
        this->_num_columns, /* num_columns */
        this->_num_rows,    /*num_rows */
        0,                  /* border num_columns*/
        0x0000000,          /* border color */
        0xFFFFFFFF          /*background color */
    );

    XSelectInput(display, window, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);
    XMapWindow(display, window);

    XWindowAttributes window_attr = {};
    XGetWindowAttributes(display, window, &window_attr);

    auto x11buffer = this->_to_x11buffer(palette);

    auto bytes_per_line = static_cast<unsigned long int>(this->_num_columns) * sizeof(DeviceColor);
    XImage *image = XCreateImage(
        display,
        window_attr.visual,
        static_cast<unsigned int>(window_attr.depth),
        ZPixmap, /* format */
        0,       /* offset */
        static_cast<char *>(x11buffer),
        this->_num_columns, /* num_columns */
        this->_num_rows,    /* num_rows */
        32,                 /* bitmap_pad */
        bytes_per_line      /* bytes_per_line */
    );

    auto gc = XCreateGC(
        display,
        window,
        0 /* valuemask */,
        NULL /*XGCValues values */
    );

    XEvent event;
    while (true) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);

        if (event.type == Expose) {
            XPutImage(
                display,
                window,
                gc,
                image,
                0,                  /* src_x */
                0,                  /* src_y */
                0,                  /* dest_x */
                0,                  /* dest_y */
                this->_num_columns, /* num_columns */
                this->_num_rows     /* num_rows */
            );
        }

        if (event.type == KeyPress)
            break;
    }

    XFreeGC(display, gc);
    XDestroyImage(image);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
}

ViewPort::ViewPort(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t num_columns, std::size_t num_rows, const std::shared_ptr<Device> device)
    : _x(x), _y(y), _num_columns(num_columns), _num_rows(num_rows), _device(device) {
    assert(num_columns >= 1);
    assert(num_rows >= 1);
    assert(x + num_columns <= device->num_columns());
    assert(y + num_rows <= device->num_rows());
}

void ViewPort::draw_vertical_line(std::size_t x, std::size_t y0, std::size_t y1, ColorId color_id) {
    const auto bot = std::min(y0, y1);
    const auto top = std::max(y0, y1);
    for (auto y = bot; y <= top; y++)
        this->set(x, y, color_id);
}

auto ViewPort::contains(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const {
    return x < this->_num_columns &&
           y < this->_num_rows;
}

auto ViewPort::get(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const {
    assert(this->contains(x, y));

    auto offset_x = this->_x + x;
    auto offset_y = this->_y + y;
    return this->_device->get(offset_x, offset_y);
}

void ViewPort::set(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, ColorId color_id) {
    assert(this->contains(x, y));

    auto offset_x = this->_x + x;
    auto offset_y = this->_y + y;
    this->_device->set(offset_x, offset_y, color_id);
}

void ViewPort::draw_line(std::size_t x0, std::size_t y0, std::size_t x1, std::size_t y1, ColorId color_id) {
    // source: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#C

    assert(this->contains(x0, y0));
    assert(this->contains(x1, y1));

    if (x0 == x1) {
        this->draw_vertical_line(x0, y0, y1, color_id);
        return;
    }

    const auto delta_x = std::abs(
        static_cast<std::int64_t>(x1) - static_cast<std::int64_t>(x0));

    const auto delta_y = std::abs(
        static_cast<std::int64_t>(y1) - static_cast<std::int64_t>(y0));

    const auto x_inc = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
    const auto y_inc = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1;

    const auto error = (delta_x > delta_y ? delta_x : -delta_y);
    auto error_over_to = error / 2;

    while (true) {
        this->set(x0, y0, color_id);

        if (x0 == x1 && y0 == y1)
            break;

        auto previous_error = error_over_to;

        if (previous_error > -delta_x) {
            error_over_to -= delta_y;

            // convoluted rewrite to avoid -Werror=sign-conversion
            // x0 += x_inc;

            const auto next_x = static_cast<int>(x0) + x_inc;
            x0 = static_cast<decltype(x0)>(next_x);
        }

        if (previous_error < delta_y) {
            error_over_to += delta_x;

            // convoluted rewrite to avoid -Werror=sign-conversion
            // y0 += y_inc;

            const auto next_y = static_cast<int>(y0) + y_inc;
            y0 = static_cast<decltype(y0)>(next_y);
        }
    }
}

auto normalized_point_to_viewport_point(const NormalizedPoint2D npt, const ViewPort &port) {
    const auto new_x = port.x() + (npt.x() * port.num_columns());
    const auto new_y = port.y() + (npt.y() * port.num_rows());

    return DevicePoint(
        static_cast<std::size_t>(new_x),
        static_cast<std::size_t>(new_y));
}

} // namespace cg
```

**src/main.cpp**

```
#include "colors.h"
#include "devices.h"
#include "universes.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cg;

int main() {
    auto num_columns = 500;
    auto num_rows = 500;
    auto dev = std::make_shared<Device>(num_columns, num_rows);

    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < dev->num_rows(); y++) {
        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < dev->num_columns(); x++) {
            dev->set(x, y, 0);
        }
    }

    auto port = cg::ViewPort(100, 100, 300, 300, dev);

    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < port.num_rows(); y += 2) {
        const auto mid_x = port.num_columns() / 2;
        const auto mid_y = port.num_rows() / 2;
        port.draw_line(mid_x, mid_y, 0, y, 1);
        port.draw_line(mid_x, mid_y, port.num_columns() - 1, y, 1);
    }

    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < port.num_columns(); x += 2) {
        const auto mid_x = port.num_columns() / 2;
        const auto mid_y = port.num_rows() / 2;
        port.draw_line(mid_x, mid_y, x, 0, 1);
        port.draw_line(mid_x, mid_y, x, port.num_rows() - 1, 1);
    }

    auto palette = Palette();
    palette.push_back(Color(0, 0, 0));
    palette.push_back(Color(1, 1, 1));

    dev->show(palette);

    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
DEBUG_OPTIONS := -g \
        -pedantic \
        -Wall \
        -Wextra \
        -Wcast-align \
        -Wcast-qual \
        -Wctor-dtor-privacy \
        -Wdisabled-optimization \
        -Wformat=2 \
        -Winit-self \
        -Wlogical-op \
        -Wmissing-include-dirs \
        -Wnoexcept \
        -Wold-style-cast \
        -Woverloaded-virtual \
        -Wredundant-decls \
        -Wsign-conversion \
        -Wsign-promo \
        -Wstrict-null-sentinel \
        -Wstrict-overflow=5 \
        -Wswitch-default \
        -Wundef \
        -Werror \
        -Wno-unused \
        -fsanitize=address

RELEASE_OPTIONS := -O2 -s -DNDEBUG -lX11

LIBS := -lX11

CPP_VERSION := -std=c++20


debug:
    g++ $(DEBUG_OPTIONS) $(CPP_VERSION) -o ./src/main.exe ./src/main.cpp $(LIBS) \
    && ./src/main.exe \
    ; rm ./src/main.exe

release:
    echo $$PATH \
    && g++ $(RELEASE_OPTIONS) $(CPP_VERSION) -o ./src/main.exe ./src/main.cpp $(LIBS) \
    && ./src/main.exe \
    ; rm ./src/main.exe
```

Comment: Good effort, includes alphabetical. Would have expected local includes (`""`) after global includeds (`<>`). VS?

Comment: Heh, vscode did the alphabetical sorting, but I think it respect the "" <> order. So I messed it up and he respected me mess. Thanks for pointing out :) I'll reorder them.

Answer (score 3):

Overall, the code is nice, clean, and modern. There aren’t really any major code smells, and it’s mostly paradigmatic.

I would say, though, that if your goal is to learn modern C++, you haven’t really done anything that flexes the true power of modern C++. For C++20, for example, the major features are concepts, coroutines, modules, and three-way comparisons… and your code doesn’t use *any* of those. In fact, at first glance, I can see only a single C++20 feature used… and it appears to be used incorrectly, and unnecessarily. That’s unfortunate, because there are a *lot* of ways you could use modern power features in a project like this. The key issue is that although you have said you want to write a graphics *library*… that’s not what you’re actually doing. You’re just writing a one-off program. You have a bunch of classes in a bunch of headers, but they hardly amount to a *library*; there doesn’t seem to be much in the way of organization, or the idea that this code is meant to be generic and reusable. You *could* write a proper graphics library, and then use that in an example program… but that’s not what you have here. And if you *did* write a proper graphics library, there would be plenty of places where C++’s modern power features will come in handy.

Pretty much the only major objection I have to the code overall is the lack of comments. There are a few sprinkled here and there, but few of them are actually useful. It doesn’t help in understanding the code to know that you had to work around a compiler warning. I have absolutely no clue, for example, what the expected output of the program is. I could compile it, run, and see what gets shown… but I would have literally no idea whether that is what it’s *supposed* to be showing. I can see the loops that draw a bunch of lines, but I can hardly be expected to run that algorithm in my head to know what it’s doing.

And that applies to lower level stuff, too. How am I (or any reviewer) expected to understand why you’re using `uint64_t` for the error in Bresenham, rather than `size_t`? Why is there an `h` member in a 2D point class? What exactly does it mean for a point to be “normalized”? All of these things could be explained with meaningful comments. Any mysteries you leave in your code are smells.

Because pretty much nothing in the code is actually *explained*, I can’t really offer many comments on whether the way you’ve done things is the best way to do them. I can’t really give you a high-level design review, because I have no idea what your high-level design *is*. The way you’ve done things may be the absolute most genius way possible, or it could be absolutely idiotic… there is simply no way for anyone to know if they don’t know what your intentions are.

So all I can do is offer a fairly low-level, nuts-and-bolts code review. It’s not much, but it’s all that’s possible.

So let’s start at the top.

## `src/universes.h`

I’m not a fan of using `.h` as a suffix for C++ header files. There is an argument that [`.h` is the right suffix for headers because headers are “often” shared between C and C++](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl27-use-a-cpp-suffix-for-code-files-and-h-for-interface-files)… but I call bullshit on that, because I can’t think of a single major C++ project of note whose headers are meant to be C-compatible, nor can I see any sensible argument for why that *should* be the norm. In any case, *your* headers are *clearly* not meant to be C headers, so that argument is moot in *this* case at least.

Now, you’ve said you want to create a graphics *library*, and that’s a good goal. It would be really cool if you could write this code is in such a way that only `main.cpp` is specific to this one program, and *everything else* is a generic, reusable graphics library. But if you’re going to create a *library*, then you should strive to separate the reusable library code from the specific program code. In other words, you should have a separate directory for the library stuff; it shouldn’t be mixed in a single `src` directory with `main.cpp`.

Also… the name “universes” makes no sense. `universes.h` has three classes; `Point2D`, `NormalizedPoint2D`, and `Window`. What does any of that have to with “universes”?

It would make more sense to have a `cg/point.hpp` header with `Point2D` and `NormalizedPoint2D`, and `cg/window.hpp` with `Window`. That also helps with dependency issues: points have no dependency on windows, for example.

```
#pragma once
```

[Don’t use `#pragma once`, use include guards](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#sf8-use-include-guards-for-all-header-files). `#pragma once` is not standardized for very good reasons.

```
class Point2D {
```

So, I’m not clear on a why a 2D point class has… 3 dimensions. Or maybe `h` isn’t a dimension? I dunno. No comments, no explanation.

In any case, there are a lot of issues with this class that really hamstring usability and performance.

The biggest issue is that, at least in debug mode, you check *every single instantiation* to make sure all the components are finite. That’s… a bit excessive. For any non-trivial application, that’s going to absolutely cripple performance.

It’s not a bad idea to check that your points have valid, finite components. The question is where it is appropriate to do that. Checking it at *every single instantiation* is… frankly… absurdly paranoid. I mean, if you *really* want that level of paranoiac protection, then you probably want a third compile mode: not just “release and debug”, but “release, debug, and paranoid”, where “debug” does reasonable checks for reasonably likely mistakes and runs slightly slower as a result, whereas “paranoid” mode checks *everything*, but runs *excruciatingly* slowly as a result.

Rather than checking *every single instantiation* of *every single point* in your program, it makes more sense to check for sanity at the point where sanity matters. In other words, you only need to check that `h` is not zero before you divide by it in `normalize()`. If you never *use* `h`… then it will never matter if it’s set to a crazy value, right? So why pay the costs of checking when you don’t need it?

Also, keep in mind that, *in practice*, you’ll probably also find that the *the vast majority* of cases where you create a point, you already know its components are valid, making the checks redundant. Again, if you have a “paranoid” mode, then, fine, be paranoid and check again. But 99% of the time, that level of paranoia is absurd, even in debug mode. And the costs you pay, both in debug mode *and in release mode* are non-trivial.

Because, yes, you *are* paying run-time costs for your paranoia. Even if you set `NDEBUG` and the `assert()`s vanish… *there is still a cost*. Even when the `assert()`s are gone, the point type remains non-trivial, because of the user-defined constructors. That’s a cost, and not a small one. If you create a large array of points… which is something that is very reasonable to do… the costs of non-triviality can explode.

So the bottom line is this: a point class should be a low-level, high-performance type, because it’s normal and reasonable for a non-trivial program to use a *lot* of them. Paranoid checking of every single point instantiation is… a bit much… and frankly, not worth the costs.

Also… I might *want* a point that’s \$(\infty,\infty)\$. I might, for example, have a search algorithm that looks for the closest point, and it’s just easier to code it if I start with a default that’s out in infinity. There might even be a situation where I want a point with one or both components as `NaN`. Unless you can say with absolute certainty that there will *never* be a use case for those, it makes no sense to ban them *completely*, rather than checking for them just in those cases where they would be problematic.

Here’s how I would implement a point class:

```
// I need a concept to make sure a type is actually a number.
//
// Unfortunately, `std::integral` accepts not only integers, but also `bool`,
// `char`, and other character types. So we need to exclude those.
//
// Note that I'm only accepting built-in number types. If you want to also
// accept user-defined number types (like big integers and so on), that's
// possible, but I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader.

template <typename T>
concept character = std::same_as<T, char>
    or std::same_as<T, char8_t>
    or std::same_as<T, char16_t>
    or std::same_as<T, char32_t>
    or std::same_as<T, wchar_t>;

template <typename T>
concept number = std::integral<T>
    or std::floating_point<T>
    // or user_defined_number<T>
    and (not character<T> or std::same_as<T, bool>);

// Base template for points.
//
// Unless you want to handle arbitrary dimensions, I wouldn’t bother defining
// the base template. I would only define specializations for 2, 3, 4, or
// whatever number of dimensions I need.
template <number T, std::size_t D>
struct point;

// 2D points.
template <number T>
struct point<T, 2>
{
    T x;
    T y;

    // Technically only `==` makes sense for points - what does it mean for a
    // point to be "less than" another point?
    //
    // But if we arbitrarily define ordering as lexicographical (first x then
    // y), then we can put points in sets and stuff more easily. It’s just for
    // convenience, and it does no harm in practice.
    constexpr auto operator<=>(point<T, 2> const&) noexcept = default;
};

// Handy alias.
using point2f = point<float, 2>;
```

You can see that, stripping out all the fluff, the point class is really just:

```
struct point
{
    float x;
    float y;
};
```

You don’t need anything more than that, and—and this is the important point—if you *add* anything more than that, you risk disabling optimization possibilities (for example, by making the class non-trivial). Less is more.

You can add operators and member functions, of course—those (generally!) won’t inhibit optimizations, especially non-member functions. You seem to want a `normalize()` function, for example. You could do:

```
template <number T>
struct point<T, 2>
{
    T x;
    T y;

    // Might also want a version that takes an epsilon.
    constexpr auto is_normalized() const -> bool
    {
        return norm_squared(*this) == T(1);
    }

    // As of C++23, you can combine these 4 operators into 1.
    constexpr auto operator[](std::size_t i) & -> T&
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0: return x;
        case 1: return y;
        }

        // In C++23 you can use std::unreachable().
        __builtin_unreachable();
    }

    constexpr auto operator[](std::size_t i) const& -> T const&
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0: return x;
        case 1: return y;
        }

        __builtin_unreachable();
    }

    constexpr auto operator[](std::size_t i) && -> T&&
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0: return std::move(x);
        case 1: return std::move(y);
        }

        __builtin_unreachable();
    }

    constexpr auto operator[](std::size_t i) const&& -> T const&&
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0: return std::move(x);
        case 1: return std::move(y);
        }

        __builtin_unreachable();
    }

    // C++23 version of all 4 above functions:
    template <typename Self>
        requires std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<Self>, point<T, 2>>
    constexpr auto operator(this Self&& self, std::size_t i) -> auto&&
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0: return std::forward<Self>(self).x;
        case 1: return std::forward<Self>(self).y;
        }

        std::unreachable();
    }
};

template <number T, std::size_t D>
constexpr auto norm_squared(point<T, D> const& p) -> T
{
    auto result = T{};
    for (auto i = std::size_t{0}; i != D; ++i)
        result += T(std::pow(p[i], 2));

    return result;
}

template <number T, std::size_t D>
constexpr auto norm(point<T, D> const& p) -> T
{
    if constexpr (D == 2)
    {
        // NOTE: Turns out that `std::hypot()` is not optimized in current
        //       compilers (unlike, say, `std::sqrt()`).
        //
        //       If that’s a concern, you could use an optimized built-in,
        //       or just the generic version below.
        return T(std::hypot(p.x, p.y));
    }
    else if constexpr (D == 3)
    {
        return T(std::hypot(p.x, p.y, p.z));
    }
    else
    {
        return T(std::sqrt(norm_squared(p)));
    }
}

template <number T, std::size_t D>
constexpr auto normalize(point<T, D> p)
{
    auto const n = norm(p);

    if (n != T{})
    {
        for (auto i = std::size_t{0}; i != D; ++i)
            p[i] /= n;

        // Or: implement operator/ with a scalar, and just do:
        //  p /= n;
    }

    return p;
}

// Usage:
//  auto const p = point<float, 2>{0.1f, 3.0f};
//  auto const p_normalized = normalize(p);
//  assert(p_normalized.is_normalized());
```

The thing to keep in mind is that if you are creating a graphics *library*, then you want your library types to be as generically useful and efficient as possible. This is especially true for a point class; for a graphics library, points are core vocabulary types. The beautiful thing about modern C++ is that `struct point { float x; float y; };` is pretty much all you need; this will give you both maximum efficiency and maximum usability. You can add stuff to that, of course, but you need to be very careful not to add things that inhibit the usability or efficiency of that simple struct. Generally, don’t add stuff you don’t need, and especially stuff that requires breaking into the guts of the class (non-member functions are fine). In particular, avoid constructors, generally (or, if you do want some useful constructors, make sure to have a defaulted default constructor, to retain triviality).

```
    auto x() const { return this->_x; }
    auto y() const { return this->_y; }
    auto h() const { return this->_h; }
```

There is no need for `this->`, except for very rare situations. It just adds clutter that makes code harder to read. (And, indeed, you will be burned by that later in the code.)

You have already decorated your member variables with a leading underscore, which is fine. That’s plenty enough.

```
class Window {
```

I would suggest that `Window` is a bad name for this class. A window is much, much more than just four numbers. Windows have titles, contents, and more.

I would suggest a better name for this class is “rectangle” (or, y’know, `rect` for short).

I would also suggest defining the rectangle in terms of 2 points, like so:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t D>
struct rect
{
    point<T, D> p1;
    point<T, D> p2;
};
```

This eliminates entire classes of problems, like `x_min` being greater than `x_max`. The cost, though is that now you can represent the same rectangle four different ways:

```
  p1          p2
    *---+       *---+
    |   |       |   |
    +---*       +---*
         p2          p1


         p1          p2
    +---*       +---*
    |   |       |   |
    *---+       *---+
  p2          p1
```

You could introduce a `canonicalize()` function to transform any of those options into the first option.

Or, you could define the rectangle as a point and a set of sizes, where the sizes must all be positive:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t D>
struct rect
{
    point<T, D> p;
    size<T, D>  size;
};
```

The `size<T, D>` class could be basically identical to the `point<T, D>` class, except instead of `x` and `y` (and `z`) it has `w` and `h` (and `d`). So the top-left corner of a rectangle `r` is `(r.p.x, r.p.y)`, and the bottom-right corner is `(r.p.x + r.size.w, r.p.y + r.size.h)`.

Either way is fine, though I’d probably use the first option, myself.

```
NormalizedPoint2D normalize(const Point2D pt, const Window &win) {
```

I’m not really sure what the point of this function is, because there is no documentation explaining what `h` is about, or what “normalization” means in this context. If the idea is to take arbitrary points and do an affine transformation where the top-right corner point becomes (0,0) and the bottom-left corner point is (1,1), then, cool, but I’d suggest the function name should be something more like `normalize_with_respect_to()`, or at least `normalize_to()` or something like that.

I would also suggest that, if the above assumption is correct, there’s no problem returning results out side of the ((0,0), (1,1)). For example, a point to the left of the middle of rectangle could be (−0.5, 0.5). There’s nothing crazy about that, and a further transform might even slide it back into the rectangle. If not, you could use a clamp function. Again, as a general rule, don’t disallow stuff needlessly; if you really need certain restrictions, limit them to where you actually need them.

## `src/colors.h`

```
const float MIN_COLOR_INTENSITY = 0.0;
const float MAX_COLOR_INTENSITY = 1.0;
const std::uint8_t MIN_CHANNEL_VALUE = 0;
const std::uint8_t MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE = 255;
```

Don’t use uppercase for constants. As a general rule, [`SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` identifiers are used for macros](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl9-use-all_caps-for-macro-names-only). If you try to use them for non-macro identifiers, you could get burned.

Also, all of these could, and should, be `constexpr`.

Also also, all of them should probably be `static` constants of the `Color` class.

```
class Color {
private:
    float _r;
    float _g;
    float _b;

public:
    Color(float r, float g, float b) {
        assert(0 <= r && r <= 1);
        assert(0 <= g && g <= 1);
        assert(0 <= b && b <= 1);

        this->_r = r;
        this->_g = g;
        this->_b = b;
    }
```

In a perfect world, I might suggest making the `r`, `g`, and `b` members public, and instead of using raw `float`s, use a clamped type that handles restricting the values to the range [0,1]. For example:

```
struct Color {
    using component_type = clamped_type<0.0f, 1.0f>;

    component_type r;
    component_type g;
    component_type b;
};
```

*However*, this is a lot of work for a simple graphics library, and, unlike with points, colours don’t really need to be as heavily optimized. You generally have a lot fewer colours knocking around, and they generally require less computation.

So I’d probably just leave it mostly as is.

```
    auto red() const { return this->_r; }
    auto green() const { return this->_r; }
    auto blue() const { return this->_r; }
```

I think you have a bug here, and all the `this->` noise is hiding it from plain sight.

This is also a pretty strong case for unit testing your code. This would have been trivial to test, and detect.

```
    std::uint32_t to_uint32() const {
        static_assert(std::endian::native == std::endian::little);

        auto value = static_cast<std::uint32_t>(MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE) << 24;
        value |= (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE * this->_r) << 16);
        value |= (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE * this->_g) << 8);
        value |= static_cast<std::uint32_t>(MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE * this->_b);
        return value;
    }
```

Not sure why the static assert is necessary. Why would there be a problem on a big-endian system?

(I suspect the problem is confusion about how endianness manifests in practice. The endianness of a machine is irrelevant in all situations… *except* when either type-punning or dealing with the raw bits and bytes of an object. And when I say “raw bits and bytes”, I don’t mean merely doing bitwise operations like `|=` or `<<`; those are completely portable (when used on unsigned types) and will produce exactly the same behaviour regardless of endianness. I mean like casting `char*` or `std::byte*` and *then* messing with the bits and bytes.)

I should also point out that you have made some curious choices about where you put your casts. For example, this line:

```
        auto value = static_cast<std::uint32_t>(MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE) << 24;
```

I suppose you assume that `value` is a `uint32_t`. It might not be. On a system with 64-bit `int`s (which is not uncommon), that `<<` operator will promote the `uint32_t` to `unsigned int`… which, again, will be 64 bits.

But you can’t just do:

```
        auto value = static_cast<std::uint32_t>(MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE << 24);
```

because the `<<` operation will promote `MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE` to *at least* 16 bits… but if it *does* only promote it to 16 bits, then the shift will blow all the data off the then. So you need to be sure that it’s at least 32 bits *before* the shift… *and* you need to make sure it hasn’t been *over*-promoted *after* the shift.

So what you probably want to do is:

```
        auto value = static_cast<std::uint32_t>(static_cast<std::uint32_t>(MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE) << 24);
```

Although, the static casting is needlessly noisy here:

```
        auto value = std::uint32_t(std::uint32_t(MAX_CHANNEL_VALUE) << 24);
```

Ugly, but that’s what you have to do to portably bit-twiddle.

The other 3 lines are fine as-is, because you’re definitely shifting (at least) 32 bits each time, and then because of `|=`, definitely cramming the result into 32 bits. (You *might* get warnings that you’re trying to stuff a larger type into 32 bits. If you definitely want to silence those potential warnings, then you’d need the double cast there, too.)

```
    auto to_device_color() const {
        return this->to_uint32();
    }
```

This function is fine *right now*… but it is brittle. It deduces the return type, which, since the only return statement is just returning the result of `to_uint32()`, will always be a `std::uint32_t`.

That’s fine *right now*, because `DeviceColor` is just an alias for `std::uint32_t`. But… will that *always* be the case? If there is any possibility that the device colour will *not* be `std::uint32_t`, you’ll get the wrong return type. And since the literal entire point of this function is specifically to return a device colour value… well, that’s not good.

This problem is trivially fixed by either disabling return deduction, or explicitly casting the return value to `DevciceColor`.

## `src/devices.h`

```
class DevicePoint {
```

This is an excellent illustration of the difference in thinking between writing a proper library, and firing off a one-shot program. In a proper library, you would probably have a point class template like the one I illustrated above… which means `DevicePoint` is just `using DevicePoint = point<std::size_t, 2>;`. Code reuse!

```
class Device {
```

I’m not sure about the name of this class. It seems misleading, because it doesn’t seem to represent any *actual* device of any sort, but merely a pixmap or canvas.

```
    auto contains(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const { return x < this->_num_columns && y < this->_num_rows; }
```

Unlike the `contains()` function in `Window` (or “rectangle”), which is probably generally useful, the only purpose for *this* `contains()` function is for assertions and sanity checking. And the only times it’s ever used are in member functions, to sanity-check assert the arguments.

As a general rule, you shouldn’t put stuff in a class’s public interface unnecessarily. Every single thing you add to a class’s public interface ***SHOULD*** be rigorously tested (hint-hint, you really should be unit testing), and everything that’s part of the public interface becomes a technical debt that you have to maintain, lest you break code that relies on it. For that reason, less is more. The less surface area a class has for users to fuck with it, the fewer bug vectors there are, and the more confident you can be that your class is safe.

There is no reason to provide this function to users. If they really, really want to be sure that they’re satisfying the preconditions for `get()` and `set()`, they can do so themselves using `num_columns()` and `num_rows()`. They don’t need `contains()`.

```
    auto get(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const;
    void set(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, ColorId color_id);
    void draw_line(std::size_t x0, std::size_t y0, std::size_t x1, std::size_t y1, ColorId color_id);
```

Why don’t these functions take `DevicePoint`s instead of raw coordinate components?

```
Device::Device(std::size_t num_columns, std::size_t num_rows)
    : _num_columns(num_columns), _num_rows(num_rows) {
    assert(num_columns >= 1);
    assert(num_rows >= 1);

    this->_buffer = std::make_unique<ColorId[]>(num_columns * num_rows);
}
```

I don’t know if you’re aware, but `make_unique()` doesn’t just allocate… it also value initializes.

What that means is that all the elements of the array are initialized to zero. So in this code (from `main()`):

```
    auto dev = std::make_shared<Device>(num_columns, num_rows);

    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < dev->num_rows(); y++) {
        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < dev->num_columns(); x++) {
            dev->set(x, y, 0);
        }
    }
```

That loop is completely redundant. All the elements are already zero.

Since C++20, there is also `make_unique_for_overwrite()`. Unlike `make_unique()`, this allocates, *but does not value-initialize*. Because `ColorId` is just a plain `int` (well, `int32_t`), that means all the elements of the array in an undefined state. Which means that you need to initialize them, as you do with that loop.

I would suggest that you consider a slightly different interface. Perhaps you could have three constructors:

```
Device(size_t w, size_t h)                  // all colour values are set to colour ID 0
Device(size_t w, size_t h, ColorId)         // all colour values are set to the given colour ID
Device(uninitialized_t, size_t w, size_t h) // all colour are undefined, and must be set before use
```

The first constructor is what you already have. The second simply delegates to the third, then fills it:

```
Device::Device(std::size_t w, std::size_t h, ColorID c)
    : Device{uninitialized, w, h}
{
    std::ranges::fill_n(_buffer.get(), w * h, c);
}
```

The third uses a tag type to signal that the colour values aren’t set. That allows users of the class to manually fill it however they want after the fact.

```
struct uninitialized_t {};
inline constexpr auto uninitialized = uninitialized_t{};

Device::Device(uninitialized_t, std::size_t w, std::size_t h)
    : _num_columns{w}
    , _num_rows{h}
{
    _buffer = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<ColorId[]>(w * h);
}
```

The tag makes it loud and clear that the device is not fully initialized, making it easy to spot situations where you *should* have initialized it.

With that interface, your `main()` function now has three options for initializing the pixmap to all zero colour IDs:

```
// Option 1 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
auto dev = std::make_shared<Device>(num_columns, num_rows);     // default to zero

// Option 2 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
auto dev = std::make_shared<Device>(num_columns, num_rows, 0);  // be explicit what colour

// Option 1 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
auto dev = std::make_shared<Device>(uninitialized, num_columns, num_rows);

// Manually fill:
for (std::size_t y = 0; y != dev->num_rows(); ++y)
{
    for (std::size_t x = 0; x != dev->num_columns(); ++x)
    {
        dev->set(x, y, 0);
    }
}
```

For other scenarios, like setting the whole canvas to a different colour, or filling it with a pattern or whatever, you have options 2 and 3.

```
auto Device::_to_x11buffer(const Palette &palette) const {
    const auto memory = malloc(this->_num_pixels() * sizeof(DeviceColor));
    const auto x_buffer = static_cast<DeviceColor *>(memory);

    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < this->_num_rows; y++) {
        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < this->_num_columns; x++) {
            const auto this_buffer_offset = this->_get_offset(x, y);

            const auto color_id = static_cast<std::size_t>(this->_buffer[this_buffer_offset]);
            const auto color = palette[color_id];
            const auto device_color = color.to_device_color();

            const auto x_buffer_offset = ((this->_num_rows - y - 1) * this->_num_columns) + x;

            x_buffer[x_buffer_offset] = device_color;
        }
    }

    return static_cast<void *>(x_buffer);
}
```

Really not a fan of this function.

I get that X is a C library, so you need to work with `malloc()` and raw C arrays. But you can still do so in a type-safe way in C++.

Returning a raw, owning pointer is a no-no in C++. Returning a raw, owning `void` pointer even more so.

What you *should* do is return a smart pointer. The catch is that you can’t just use a basic `unique_ptr`, because, by default, `unique_ptr` will delete using `delete`… not `free()`.

This is an easy catch to fix, though. `unique_ptr` allows specifying a custom deleter. You can just do so:

```
struct free_deleter
{
    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto operator()(T* p) const noexcept
    {
        if (p)
            std::free(p);
    }
};

const auto memory = std::malloc(this->_num_pixels() * sizeof(DeviceColor));
const auto x_buffer = std::unique_ptr<DeviceColor[], free_deleter>{memory};
```

And the rest of the function, except for the return line, is the same. The return line is just `return x_buffer;`.

And in `show()`, you just do this:

```
    auto x11buffer = this->_to_x11buffer(palette);

    auto bytes_per_line = static_cast<unsigned long int>(this->_num_columns) * sizeof(DeviceColor);
    XImage *image = XCreateImage(
        display,
        window_attr.visual,
        static_cast<unsigned int>(window_attr.depth),
        ZPixmap, /* format */
        0,       /* offset */
        static_cast<char *>(x11buffer.get()),
        this->_num_columns, /* num_columns */
        this->_num_rows,    /* num_rows */
        32,                 /* bitmap_pad */
        bytes_per_line      /* bytes_per_line */
    );

    // Now, after verifying that XCreateImage() succeeded, you do:
    x11buffer.release();

    // If XCreateImage() did not succeed, you simply throw an exception.
    // The buffer memory is automatically cleaned up.
```

Speaking of `Device::show()`… this is the most problematic part of the program, but it’s not entirely your fault. The problem is that X is a C library, so it just doesn’t play well with C++. You have multiple options for how you can fix that.

The most in-depth is to create a C++ wrapper library around X. This costs the most up-front, but has the biggest payoffs in the long term. However, for a simple project… it can be a bit much.

The second most in-depth is to create a library of RAII objects that will handle the cleanup for the stuff you need. It would be nice if this were included as part of the C++ standard, and there have been efforts for a long time to include things like `scope_exit` and `unique_resource`. But for now, you will mostly have to roll your own, which is a fair amount of work to get right, though it does have big payoffs.

The easiest option is to cheat a bit, using `unique_ptr` and custom deleters. This takes the least amount of work in the short term. Unfortunately, X is terrible, so you can’t use this option for everything, at least not directly. But it can get you a lot of the way.

For functions that return a pointer, the easy option is trivial. Simply use `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter:

```
struct x_deleter
{
    auto operator()(Display* p) const noexcept
    {
        if (p)
            XCloseDisplay(p);
    }
};

void Device::show(const Palette &palette) const {

    auto const display = std::unique_ptr<Display, x_deleter>{XOpenDisplay(nullptr)};
    assert(display != nullptr);

    auto window = ::XCreateSimpleWindow(
        display.get(),  // Note: have to use .get()
        // ... [snip] ...
    );

    // If creating window fails, you can throw, and the display will
    // automatically be cleaned up.

    // ... [snip] ...

    XFreeGC(display, gc);
    XDestroyImage(image);

    // Don’t need this anymore!
    // XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```

This trick can also work for graphics contexts, because those are also secretly pointers, but it takes a little more work. Alternately, you can use `unique_ptr` to create a *pointer* to a `GC`, and a custom deleter that not only `delete`s the pointer, but also calls `XFreeGC()`. That’s wasteful and ugly but… it’s really the only *proper* way to do it, without a custom RAII class or something like `unique_resource` or `scope_exit`.

With those RAII tools, you can properly handle errors easily, which you currently do not handle at all.

I would also suggest that `show()` shouldn’t be a member function of `Device` (which is really just a pixmap). It seems more like it should be a free function that takes a pixmap and a pallete, and maybe a display too.

```
class ViewPort {
private:
    std::size_t _x;
    std::size_t _y;
    std::size_t _num_columns;
    std::size_t _num_rows;
    std::shared_ptr<Device> _device;
```

This class seems to be just a rectangle, with a canvas (that doesn’t seem to share the same dimensions as the rectangle), and some drawing functions.

The thing that bothers me most about this class is that shared pointer. `shared_ptr` is a code smell, because it usually means someone doesn’t really understand what they’re doing. Shared ownership is *sometimes* necessary… but *almost never*. 99.99999% of the time, it’s used by people who don’t really understand the structure of their code, like which components are responsible for what, or they’re using it because they tried a `unique_ptr` first, got compile errors, and switched it to `shared_ptr` to shut them up.

Can you really make the case that a viewport has to *own* a device… and *share* that devices with other stuff? That seems unlikely. It would mean that you think it should be perfectly normal that when you’re drawing lines, it’s fine if something, somewhere else scribbles all over your work. “I drew a line… but it’s not here! What happened? Oh… some other part of the program filled the canvas with white after I drew the line.” That doesn’t seem like what anyone would want in a drawing class.

It *may* be the case that the device is a resource that can be shared among multiple objects (view ports)… but in that case, should the view ports *own* the device? Or should they merely have a *pointer* to it. Not every pointer needs to be smart. [It is perfectly fine to have a raw pointer as a non-owning or reseatable reference to something](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r3-a-raw-pointer-a-t-is-non-owning).

I can’t tell you what the *right* solution here is, because the lack of comments and explanation means I don’t really know what is desired or intended. All I can say is… this looks wrong.

I would suggest that any time you ever feel tempted to use a `shared_ptr`, you stop, and consider ***EVERY OTHER POSSIBILITY***, and only use `shared_ptr` if you really, truly, seriously, actually mean for something to be shared among multiple owners. Which, frankly, will be (almost) never.

As for the rest of the class, pretty much everything I said to `Device` applies here.

```
auto normalized_point_to_viewport_point(const NormalizedPoint2D npt, const ViewPort &port) {
```

This function does not appear to be used.

## `src/main.cpp`

```
using namespace cg;
```

Not a fan. No, not even in source files.

It (probably!) won’t be a problem in a small, simple program. But seriously `cg::` is literally just four characters long. And you already use it anyway when creating the view port.

```
    auto dev = std::make_shared<Device>(num_columns, num_rows);
```

It seems like the only reason to create a shared pointer here is because you need one in the view port object. That’s a pretty glaring sign of an interface problem. It shouldn’t matter whether devices are created on the stack or not.

In fact, there are a couple of places where your interface forces types unnecessarily. The need for a shared pointer in the view port is one, but there’s also this:

```
using Palette = std::vector<Color>;

void Device::show(const Palette &palette) const {
```

Why does the palette need to be a vector? Why can’t it be an array? Or, why can’t it be a `std::pmr::vector<Color>`, where I’ve used a specialized, highly-optimized memory resource?

This is a good place to step back and really think about what you need in a a palette. It doesn’t need to be a vector. All it needs to be (if you ignore the validation function) is a collection of colours that can be accessed by index. In C++-speak, that’s a random-access range of `Color`. (If you include the validation function, it also needs to be a *sized* range.)

So you could do this (ignoring validation):

```
template <typename T>
concept palette = std::ranges::random_access_range<T>
    and std::same_as<Color, std::ranges::range_value_t>;    // or, for more flexibility, constructible_from

template <palette P>
auto Device::_to_x11buffer(P&& pal) const
{
    auto x_buffer = std::unique_ptr<DeviceColor[], free_deleter>{std::malloc(_num_pixels() * sizeof(DeviceColor)};

    for (std::size_t y = 0; y != _num_rows; ++y)
    {
        for (std::size_t x = 0; x != _num_columns; ++x)
        {
            auto const this_buffer_offset = ;

            auto const color_id = _buffer[_get_offset(x, y)];
            auto const color = palette[color_id];
            auto const device_color = color.to_device_color();

            auto const x_buffer_offset = ((_num_rows - y - 1) * _num_columns) + x;

            x_buffer[x_buffer_offset] = device_color;
        }
    }

    return x_buffer;
}

template <palette P>
auto Device::show(P&& pal) const
{
    // ... [snip] ...

    auto x11buffer = _to_x11buffer(std::forward<P>(pal));

    // ... [snip] ...
}
```

Which, as you can see, is pretty much identical to the existing code, except now much, much more flexible, because you can use *anything* as a palette: vectors, arrays, custom types, and so on.

## `Makefile`

```makefile
DEBUG_OPTIONS := -g \
```

[It’s better to reserve `ALL_CAPS` identifiers for environment variables, and use lower case for internal variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html#Using-Variables). This style rule isn’t nearly as widely accepted as the C++ one about macro identifiers, though.

Also, I believe `:=` is not portable; the portable equivalent is `::=`.

In any case, I’m not a fan of setting a shit-ton of compiler options in the makefile. This can cause problems on systems that don’t use the exact same compiler, even if it’s just a different version. Most of the warning options you’ve set aren’t even relevant to your program. This is just cargo-cult coding, where you just copy-paste junk off StackOverflow or wherever, without really giving any thought as to whether it applies to your case.

I’m also not really a fan of having “release” and “debug” targets in a makefile. If I want a “release” version, I’ll provide the flags I want… which may include the ones you’ve chosen, and may not. I may decide I *don’t* want to strip the executable, and I may want to use `-march=native`. Same goes for the “debug” version; if I want to debug the program, I probably have a very specific set of flags in mind.

I would suggest *not* putting all this stuff in a makefile, and instead maybe putting the set of flags you like to use for debugging or whatever in environment variables, defined in your profile, that you can set or not as you please.

In fact, here’s roughly what I like the compiling and linking commands in a makefile to look like:

```makefile
# Link command:
${exe} : ${obj}
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${CPPFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -o ${@} ${^} ${LDLIBS}

# Compile command:
${obj} : %.o : %.cpp
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${CPPFLAGS} -c -o ${@} ${<}
```

Why? Because I might (and very often do) want to compile a program with Clang instead of (or in addition to) GCC. So I can set `CXX` to `clang++` if I want that. I can control whether I want to compile in C++20 mode or a *future* standard mode (`-std=c++26`) by how I set `CXXFLAGS`.

I would say your makefile really misses the whole point of using make to begin with. You could just use a simple shell script instead. The whole point of `make` is that it figures out the dependency graph, and only compiles/links what’s necessary. You just recompile ***EVERYTHING***, *every* time. Why bother with `make` then?

I also don’t see the sense in *deleting* the exe after each make run. What if I want to run it multiple times to time it?

Here’s basically how I would write your makefile:

```makefile
# Configuration ########################################################

exe ::= src/main.exe

src ::= src/main.cpp

LDLIBS ::= ${LDLIBS} -lX11

# Standard configuration ###############################################

# Generally a good idea to specify the shell
SHELL ::= /bin/sh

# Restrict the suffixes to the ones used by C++
.SUFFIXES :
.SUFFIXES : .cpp .hpp .o

# Nice shortcut alias
obj ::= ${src:.cpp=.o}

# Default target #######################################################

.PHONY : all
all : ${exe}

# Dependencies #########################################################

# Normally I would use dependency sniffing to figure this out, rather
# than manually writing out the dependencies, but for this illustration,
# this will serve.

src/main.o : src/main.cpp src/colors.h src/devices.h src/universes.h

# Link #################################################################

${exe} : ${obj}
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${CPPFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -o ${@} ${^} ${LDLIBS}

# Compile ##############################################################

${obj} : %.o : %.cpp
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${CPPFLAGS} -c -o ${@} ${<}

# Clean ################################################################

.PHONY : clean
clean : clean-obj
    -@rm -rf -- ${exe}

# For when I want to clean everything but leave the final exe (and any
# supporting libs):
.PHONY : clean-obj
clean-obj :
    -@rm -rf -- ${obj}
```

This is roughly the basic makefile I have set up that I simply copy into every new project. All I need to do is change the executable name, change the list of sources, and I’m off. (In the real version, I detect the dependencies automatically, so I don’t even need to specify those. Also, by default, I just use all `*.cpp` files in the source directory as the source files, recursively (except for `*.test.cpp` files, which I separate out and use as unit tests.)

If I were doing debugging, I would do something like this:

```sh
# In a new shell...

# Set up the flags I want...
export CXXFLAGS='-std=c++20 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -g -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual (any other flags)'

# And... done.
```

Now I can call `make` as many times as I please while I mess with the code, or do whatever.

Then if I wanted to try it with Clang, I might do

```sh
# In a new shell...

# Choose clang
export CXX=clang++

# Set up the flags I want...
export CXXFLAGS='-std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -march=native -s -O2'

# And... done.
```

And again, I can just keep calling `make` as many times as I please. `make clean` will clean everything up, if necessary.

It doesn’t really make much difference with this, a single file program. But if you start building an *actual* library, you will probably find it makes a *huge* difference to only rebuild stuff that needs rebuilding.

Comment: Such a thorough answer! Thank you kindly! I'll update my question  (without updating the code posted here) to elaborate on some points

Answer (score 2):

Has this been standardized across all compilers?

```
#pragma once
```

---

Prefix underscore can be problomatic.

```
    float _x;
    float _y;
    float _h;
```

Do you know the rules. Most people get them wrong. So just having to explain the rules can cause issues (you happen to be OK). But usually not worth the effort or time. If you must distinguish member variable names use a suffix rather than a prefex.

---

Better to only use your previous constructror and have the third parameter have a default value. That way you only have one constructor.

```
    Point2D(float x, float y) : Point2D(x, y, 1) {}
```

---

Don't use `this->` it hides potential errors.

```
auto x() const { return this->_x; }
auto y() const { return this->_y; }
```

The only reason to use `this->` is to diferentiate between member and a local shadowing variable. Otherwise you can simply use the member name.

If you have a shadowing variable name (which the compiler will warn you about as it is bad practice), then you have to know the code to make sure you are using the correct variable. Also if you use the wrong name the compiler can not know you are using the wrong one so can not issues warnings.

This problem is resolved by using distinct variable names that are obvious to understand given the context. Thus resolving the problem and also removing the need to use `this->`.

---

I like the use of `auto` in your previous methods. It makes changing the types of the memebrs easier (though it does break the open closed principle).

But in this case. I don't like the use of `auto`. It is not obvious htis returns a `bool`without reading the actual code. This interface is neve going to change.

```
    auto contains(Point2D pt) const {
        return this->_min_x <= pt.x() && pt.x() <= this->_max_x && this->_min_y <= pt.y() && pt.y() <= this->_max_y;
    }
```

So here I would adivce explicitly setting the return type. Either the old (on the left) or the new (on the right).

---

Personally I don't like `assert()` as it does not do anything in production code where asserts are removed.

```
Window::Window(float min_x, float min_y, float max_x, float max_y)
    : _min_x(min_x),
      _min_y(min_y),
      _max_x(max_x),
      _max_y(max_y) {
    assert(std::isfinite(min_x));
    assert(std::isfinite(min_y));
    assert(std::isfinite(max_x));
    assert(std::isfinite(max_y));

    assert(min_x < max_x);
    assert(min_y < max_y);
}
```

These asserts don't provide any pprotection. Should this not be an exception. Use asserts when you are validating pre/post conditions on your type's invariants before/after a mthod call.

They should not for used for checking or validating user input.

---

Why not use the initializer list here?

```
    Color(float r, float g, float b) {
        this->_r = r;
        this->_g = g;
        this->_b = b;
    }
```

---

Couple of bugs here!

```
    auto red() const { return this->_r; }
    auto green() const { return this->_r; }  // mmmmm
    auto blue() const { return this->_r; }   // mmmmm
```

---

This pattern:

```
Create
   Use
Destroy
```

Is an anti pattern in C++ because it is not exception safe.

We prefer to use RAII to control resource creation and destruction via the constructor/destructor.

You can see this pattern here:

```
void Device::show(const Palette &palette) const {
    auto *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    XImage *image = XCreateImage(
        display,
        window_attr.visual,
        static_cast<unsigned int>(window_attr.depth),
        ZPixmap, /* format */
        0,       /* offset */
        static_cast<char *>(x11buffer),
        this->_num_columns, /* num_columns */
        this->_num_rows,    /* num_rows */
        32,                 /* bitmap_pad */
        bytes_per_line      /* bytes_per_line */
    );

    auto gc = XCreateGC(
        display,
        window,
        0 /* valuemask */,
        NULL /*XGCValues values */
    );

    /// Work

    XFreeGC(display, gc);
    XDestroyImage(image);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```

I would create some wrappers to these objects (or use some standard ones).

---

Comment: Woah! Thanks for the feedback! I really messed Color class huh?